# Get Twitter details from selected account SLComposeViewController

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, slcomposeviewcontroller

I can get twitter details Using `ACAccountStore` but my question is using `SLComposeViewController`.
when i want to share my tweet along with it i want to get twitter id and profile image url. 
          i have multiple accounts and on selecting one i want to get Twitter id of that selected account.

Is there any way to get selected account from multiple accounts present in settings??

Thanks in advance

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately No, Its not possible to get the selected account details from `SLComposeViewController`. Apple doesnt give any options to access the selected account. Refer https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Reference/SLComposeViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html